# create image programmatically in objective-c based on coreData info

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a table in my ViewController, in this table I will get some information from webService and CoreData, this information comes in each rows, when I press in each row, I want to go to the detail view and create image,

I have card and in each card I have different stamp, when I'm going to detailView I want to create this images, I mean if my card has 2 stamp I want to create 2 image, if 3 stamp I want to create 3 image,

would you please help me in this implementation,
Thanks in advance!

Here is info that I got from web service:

```
createdAt = 1362412409;
id = 2;
stampNumber = 2;
   },
   {
        createdAt = 1362069567;
        id = 1;
        stampNumber = 10;
   }
```

Here is my Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
    *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CardsCell";
    CardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil){
         NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardCell" owner:nil 
    options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in objects)
                    {
                        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                        {
                            cell = (CardCell *) currentObject;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
    }
    card = self.cards[indexPath.row];

    cell.stampId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",card.stampNumber];
    cell.createdAt.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",card.createdAt];
    cell.CardId.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Carte %d",(indexPath.row+1)];
    return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
     *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"cardDetail" object:nil 
    userInfo:nil];
}
```

my question is how should I create this pictures programatically based on my stamp..

**Edit:**
I have this image:

```
UIImageView *stampIMG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
stampIMG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
stampIMG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 122, 122);
```

I just want to use this image

Comment: I'm confused. What is this image supposed to look like? What is a "stamp"? All I see is a "stampId" which appears to be a number. How do you plan to create an image from a number?

Comment: @maddy I will created image based on that number

Comment: Based on the number how? Where does the image content come from? Or do you simply want an image of the number?

Comment: OK, you already have the images. You don't actually want to create the images at runtime. Correct? Your question is really about how to reference an existing image based on the stamp id? For that you can do something like `[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", stampId]];`. Update the format specifier to match the type of `stampId`.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I have one image, I want to check if my stamp number is 1 put 2 image(the images is the same), if my stamp number is 3 put 3 image

Answer (score 0):

You should store a path to the image location not the NSData for the image. Then use stampId to get that image path and load in your image. If the image is on the server then download the image. You could store the image as NSData in CoreData but this blob could be large that's why it's typically better to just store the path to the image. So in CoreData you could have an object Stamp which has stampId and ImagePath. Then fetch the object by stampId and then get the imagePath out of the object.

I'd probably try something like this to get the image by stamp id. Substitute document directory vs main bundle if your images are downloaded.

```
NSFetchRequest * stampById = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[stampById setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContextBKG]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stampId == %@", stampId];
[stampById setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * stampResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:stampById error:&error];

if(nil != stampResults && [stampResults count]){
    Stamp *stamp = [stampResults objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: stamp.imagePath ofType:@"png"]];
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to show the basic idea. Once again this is if you are using coreData. IF not there are way easier ways as suggested like `stringWithFormat`

Comment: Thanks , with this way:if I had 2 stamp can I have 2 image? (the images store in my local and it's just one image) when my stamp ID increased I want to have the same number of images